# How to start a flow from a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, after-trigger

I am new totriggers and trying to start a flow from a trigger but get the error:
`Constructor not defined: [Flow.Interview.Create_Renewal_OppLineItems_from_Invoice_record].<Constructor>()`

See my code:

```
trigger StartFlow on Order__c (after insert, after update ) {
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
    Flow.Interview.Create_Renewal_OppLineItems_from_Invoice_record DummyFlow = new Flow.Interview.Create_Renewal_OppLineItems_from_Invoice_record();
        DummyFlow.start();

      }
}
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this link.
https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/10/26/calling-flow-from-apex/

This link provides detailed information on how to call flows from apex.

Comment: I used that example for my trigger. In my case I just need to start the flow without any values passed

Comment: Hi @Koen Certyn! Would you mind adding details from the link you posted, it happens that links tend to break and thus becomes useless (along with your answer). Please include the essentials of it and update your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use Process Builder instead of trigger. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_flow.htm&type=0

Comment: The problem I am having now is that PB is not stable enough

Comment: What did you mean ?

Comment: When PB is intensively Used it tends not to fire

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the flow as below:

Flow.Interview.myFlow startFlow= new Flow.Interview.myFlow(new Map<String, Object>());